# Docusign, how getting an access token without logging(authorization) in browser

Tags: docusignapi

I make requests to the docusign API on the backend where I want to get an access token, is it possible to get an acess token without authorization in the browser?

Comment: Yes. You need to use the `OAuth` `JWT` application authentication flow. (https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that by using the Json Web Token Model of OAuth.
You would still need to obtain consent one per-user/app, but once obtained, you can get tokens for this using an API call without having the need for a web browser or user to login.
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/ should help you step-by-step getting JWT tokens.